# Is there a better way to use the values from either table a or table b?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have three tables: `orders`, `user_addresses` and `alternate_addresses`. A user always has a user_address. An order has an `alternate_address_id`, which may contain an `alternate_address_id` or `NULL`.

Right now my query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  IF(ISNULL(orders.alternate_address_id), a.firstname, u.firstname) AS firstname,
  IF(ISNULL(orders.alternate_address_id), a.lastname, u.lastname) AS lastname
  -- etc.
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN alternate_addresses a ON (
  orders.alternate_address_id IS NOT NULL
  AND orders.alternate_address_id = a.alternate_address_id)
LEFT JOIN user_addresses u ON (
  orders.alternate_address_id IS NULL
  AND orders.user_id = u.user_id)
```

It seems kind of redundant doing the `IF(ISNULL())` part for every address field, since I know which address I need to use after the first one.

Is there a better way to do this (I cannot change the design of the tables)?

Thanks for your thoughts
.

Comment: [COALESCE()?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: I considered that. But if the alternate_address didn't have, let's say a company_name, it would mix in a possible user_addresses.company_name, which would be a problem.

Comment: you say you can't change the table design. Can you at least change the application logic so that each order has a alternate_address (which is by default the same as the user_address)? I think it's even better in logical terms, since your past orders will have the address where they were actually sent, even if the user changes his/her current address later.

Comment: I'm afraid not. This is an existing application I'm doing a minor change on.

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem here is that `user_addresses` and `alternate_addresses` are different tables. Because they are different tables it's going to be hard to get SQL to treat them uniformly.

It would be much better design to have a single addresses table, which can be referred to by users and (optionally) by orders, and then you would be able to devise a JOIN condition which joined to the correct address for each order.

Comment: While that may be true, it is not an option to change the db design. And your answer would be better suited in the comments section. Thanks anyway.

Comment: For some reason people don't like `UNION`, but it's a powerful tool which allows you to not mash heterogeneous data into one ugly table with tons of NULL columns.

Comment: Sure, but there was no evidence in the question that user_addresses and alternate_addresses actually were heterogeneous: from the information we had, it seemed like they were similar/the same structure. Certainly you could JOIN to a UNION of user_addresses+alternate_addresses in a full SQL database; I'm not sure if mysql can do that.

Comment: From my experience, "tag" columns are annoying even when the tables merged have the same structure. MySQL can do `UNION`, as well as `PRIMARY KEY (user_id, is_primary_or_alternate_address_tag)`. And `UNION` should go after `JOIN`... or indeed, I can `UNION` two `SELECT *, 1 AS is_primary_or_alternate_address_tag FROM user_addresses` and `SELECT *, 0 AS is_primary_or_alternate_address_tag FROM alternate_addresses`, and then do `JOIN`... but I doubt MySQL can optimize that.

Comment: But that's not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about `SELECT ... FROM a JOIN (b UNION c) ON ...` which is valid SQL but I suspect mysql doesn't support it (it doesn't appear in the grammar at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html anyhow). Here you would UNION the user_addresses table with the alternate_addresses table (to get in effect a global addresses table) and have the JOIN condition pick the right address depending on whether the order had an alternate address ID set or not.

Comment: @drquicksilver, actually, in this case, I'm probably wrong, and your approach is better. I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, with the UNION approach I'll have two records in my result set, which I will then have to check programmatically and pick one?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.firstname AS firstname, a.lastname AS lastname, ...
FROM orders
JOIN alternate_addresses a ON (orders.alternate_address_id = a.alternate_address_id)

UNION

SELECT u.firstname AS firstname, u.lastname AS lastname, ...
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN user_addresses u ON (orders.user_id = u.user_id)
WHERE orders.alternate_address_id IS NULL
```

Actually, drquicksilver has the point. It would be better to have on `addresses` table, with an additional column for the type of the address (main, alternative, what else?). Now `alternate_address_id` is not needed, instead of it you reference one of the addresses of the user. `FOREIGN KEY (user_id, address_id) REFERENCES addresses (user_id, address_id)`, or something along these lines.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't really solving the problem though? This would give me two result sets which I'd have to choose between in the program code.

Comment: No, it gives you *one* result set. `UNION` is SQL operator.

Comment: Sorry, wrong term. One result set, 2 "rows" in the result set.

Comment: Sorry, it's me, forgot the `WHERE`. Sometimes I miss D's special joins `MATCHING`/`NOT MATCHING`.